# Array separating output data

Tags: php

one other question

```
$_SESSION['files'][] = $sid . '-' . $data['Id'] . '-reg'
$_SESSION['files'][] = $sid . '-' . $data['Id'] . '-nor'
...
```

the files session should look like this when echoed

```
317e2b5a2376dd19cb5fc431bced949a-56-reg
```

how do i take $_SESSION['files'][] and separate the data into these variable $sid, $id, $type using - and the separator... something like this.

```
$sid = "317e2b5a2376dd19cb5fc431bced949a";
$id = "56";
$type = "reg";
```

following **codaddict** below example something like this would be right correct?

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['files']);$i++) {
list($sid,$id,$type) = explode('-',$_SESSION['files'][$i]);
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode):

```
list($sid, $id, $type) = explode('-', $filename, 3);
```

Or [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf):

```
sscanf($filename, '%s-%s-%s', $sid, $id, $type);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**explode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function as:

```
list($sid,$id,$type) = explode('-',$_SESSION['files'][$index]);
```

[Ideone link](http://www.ideone.com/UWdLe)

Comment: does this look right for my For statement?

for($i=0;$i<count($_SESSION['files']);$i++) {
list($sid,$id,$type) = explode('-',$_SESSION['files'][$i]);
...
}